# EasyAPNS when fetching queued messages in Production- Empty clientid column

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, ios5, apple-push-notifications

I have alrealy set APNS server with easyAPNS, everything is ok, certificates, permissions, devices are registered correctly, messages are created at messages table. But the issue is that when I try to fetch queded messages, the function in class_APNS.php:

```
private function _flushMessages(){
        // only send one message per user... oldest message first
        $sql = "SELECT
                `apns_messages`.`pid`,
                `apns_messages`.`message`,
                `apns_devices`.`devicetoken`,
                `apns_devices`.`development`
            FROM `apns_messages`
            LEFT JOIN `apns_devices` ON (`apns_devices`.`pid` = `apns_messages`.`fk_device` AND `apns_devices`.`clientid` = `apns_messages`.`clientid`)
            WHERE `apns_messages`.`status`='queued'
                AND `apns_messages`.`delivery` <= NOW()
                AND `apns_devices`.`status`='active'
            ORDER BY `apns_messages`.`created` ASC
            LIMIT 100;";

        $this->_iterateMessages($sql);
    }
```

doesn't iterate any messages, because devices and messages clientid column values are empty, so de the clausule (`apns_devices`.`pid` = `apns_messages`.`fk_device` AND `apns_devices`.`clientid` = `apns_messages`.`clientid`) is never acomplished.

Here is the samples.php snippet code I use to create messages:

```
$apns->newMessage(4);
$apns->addMessageAlert('Si us plau!!!');
$apns->addMessageCustom('acme2', array('bang', 'whiz'));
$apns->queueMessage();
```

I really appreciate your help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I modified the query in this way:

`$sql = "SELECT
                    apns_messages.pid,
                    apns_messages.message,
                    apns_devices.devicetoken,
                    apns_devices.development
                FROM apns_messages
                LEFT JOIN apns_devices ON (apns_devices.clientid = apns_messages.clientid)
                WHERE apns_messages.status='queued'
                    AND apns_messages.delivery <= NOW()
                    AND apns_devices.status='active'
                ORDER BY apns_messages.created ASC
                LIMIT 1000;";`

and to send more than 100 messages

`$tv_sec = 0;`

$tv_usec = 200000;

It seems to work fine.